# Accessing JSON elements using indexes in PL/SQL

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I want to access JSON inner elements in PL/SQL.I'm using oracle 12c release 2.

```
    `{"widget": [
    "debug": "on",
    "window": {
        "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    },
    "image": { 
        "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 250,
        "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
]} `
```

In the above JSON can I navigate through by using '.' or indexes in PL/SQL?
i.e. `widget[0].window.width` to get an inner element width.

I want to modify/add JSON elements using navigation instead of creating new object.
Is this Possible ?
Thanks.

Comment: Native JSON handling was added in 12cR1 and improved in later releases, so it would be useful to include the Oracle version you are using. Any code you've currently tried might be helpful too; and do you actually need to use PL/SQL?

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for the response...  I'm using 12c release 2.  I tried using separate JSON Objects for modifications..instead of declaring several JSON objects, navigating through will make my work much easier..and yes I need to use PL/SQL  :)

Comment: Lot's of good information on this page.
http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2017/11/json-in-oracle-database-resources-to.html

Comment: Some examples in parsing JSON using PLSQL here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/json-and-plsql-a-match-made-in-database